# create CollectionViewSource in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code in my xaml

```
<local:MyDataSource x:Key="MyData" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyData}, Path=Summaries}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

which I would like to transfer to my code behind.

`MyDataSource` is a public class, which I already have. It contains a collection which should fill the `CollectionViewSource`, in order to bind it to a `listView`.

I've been looking for a while now for some kind of tutorial or something but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var collView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyData.Summaries);
collView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));
```

your summaries collection must be

```
IEnumerable or IListSource
```